# SAX XML Java Entities problem

Tags: java, xml, sax

I've a problem with **SAX** and **Java**.

I'm parsing the *dblp* digital library database xml file (which enumerates journal, conferences, paper). The XML file is very large (> 700MB).

However, my problem is that when the callback **characters()** returns, if the string retrieved contains several *entities*, the method only returns the string starting from the last entity characters *found*.

i.e.: `R&uuml;diger Mecke` is the original author name held between `<author>` tags

`üdiger Mecke` is the result

(The String returned from *characters (ch[], start, length)* method).

I would like to know:

1. how to prevent the PArser to automatically resolve entities?
2. how to solve the truncated characters problem previously described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`characters()` is not guaranteed to return of all the characters in a single call.  From the Javadoc:

> The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character
>   data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single
>   chunk, or they may split it into several chunks.

You need to append the characters returned in all of the calls, something like:

```
private StringBuffer tempValue = new StringBuffer();

startElement()
{
    tempValue.setLength(0); // clear buffer...
}

characters(characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
{
    tempValue.append(ch, start, length); // append to buffer
}

endElement()
{
    String value = tempValue.toString(); // use characters in buffer...
}
```

Comment: What determines the chunks that the parser returns? My file contains a &quot;, and that seems to delimit parsing.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think you can turn off entity resolution.
2. The characters method can be called multiple times for a single tag, and you have to collect the characters across the multiple calls rather than expecting them all to arrive at once.

Comment: ok, but why characters method is called multiple time only for text node holding entities?

Comment: I don't believe that's the only thing that will cause multiple calls, but I know it does in most implementations of sax.  Long blocks might also be split.