# Proper way to store an url in xml?

Tags: xml, sax

I am storing data in xml file,
In one of the node I have to store an url which consists of special character like &
I used &amp instead of & and xml shows no error but when I did SAX parsing String value returned within the node is the string which is after &,

I am guessing the way I am storing the url is not proper.

What is right way of storing an url in xml.

Currently I am storing as,

```
<param>http://www.example.com?param1=abc&amp;v=1</param>
```

XML has no errors, but SAX parser won't return the whole url.

EDIT: I have semicolon after &amp in the url, I missed it the first time.

**Solution:** It was not the problem with XML , but the way I handled XML in XMLHandler,
I was using new String(ch,start,length);
Now changed to stringBuilder();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML is correct (now that you have added the semi-colon), so your use of the SAX API must be wrong.

Maybe see the following answer: [Sax parsing and encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890404/sax-parsing-and-encoding/1891230#1891230)

Comment: It worked, Thank you :) After 4 min, I will mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 3):

You need a semicolon (`;`) after the `&amp`:

```
<param>http://www.example.com?param1=abc&amp;v=1</param>
```

EDIT: Okay, now that this has been clarified a bit, I think the issue is that SAX doesn't have to return the entire string in a single `characters()` call. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556086/sax-xml-java-entities-problem) question for more information on how to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry, I missed ; , I have updated the question. I have semicolon in the url.

Comment: @sat: Well, in that case your SAX parser should be returning the whole string. What *does* the SAX parser return?

Comment: It returns me v=1 with above url being parsed in SAX

Comment: I got the solution, it was buffering problem. fixed it in SAXHandler itself.

Answer (score 0):

if `ampv` is param then:

```
<param>http://www.example.com?param1=abc&amp;ampv=1</param>
```

else if `v` is param:

```
<param>http://www.example.com?param1=abc&amp;v=1</param>
```