# TestNG how to pass a URL as a parameter?

Tags: testng, selenium-grid

I am trying to pass a URL as a parameter in TestNG. However I am facing an issue with equal symbol =.

In fact this is my URL :

http://frstmwarwebsrv.orsyptst.com:9000/duobject?searchString=CRM%20:&filtercheck=nameSWF&p.index=0&p.size=8

Here is how I am passing the URL in testng.xml file :

```
<test name="API">
    <parameter name="URL" value="URL = http://frstmwarwebsrv.orsyptst.com:9000//duobject?searchString=CRM%20:&filtercheck=nameSWF&p.index=0&p.size=8"" />

    <classes>
        <class name="Distributed.Search" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

I am getting this error :

org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 156; columnNumber: 102; The reference to entity "filtercheck" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Any idea how can I overcome this problem?

Thanks
Zied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it is not closed. Maybe someone will close it.

Problem related to not escaping the special charactrs in XML. Related to: [Proper way to store an url in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942999/proper-way-to-store-an-url-in-xml)